# Is there a way to force "if" to only accept boolean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

The following code is legal in TypeScript:

```
let asyncCondition = async(): Promise<boolean> => // .. calculate & return a boolean
if(asyncCondition()){ // forgot to await. condition is always true
  // .. do stuff
}
```

Since `asyncCondition()` returns a normal not-null `Promise`, the code in `if` block will always get executed. This is JavaScript behavior and it's understandable that TypeScript doesn't complain.

But in the above scenario, what I really meant is:

```
let asyncCondition = async(): Promise<boolean> => // .. calculate & return a boolean
if(await asyncCondition()){ // condition is asyncCondition()
  // .. do stuff
}
```

Is there a way to let TypeScript to type check this kind of errors for me?

Comment: Probably it's a matter of habit to put check against Boolean true in your if condition, eg: if(await asyncCondition() === true){

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler does not do it and I won't expect it to do it any time soon. It has been asked and rejected a number of times. The cases I could find:

- Feb 2016: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7306
- Apr 2016: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8178
- Jul 2016: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9702

In each cases, the reasoning for closing these issues without changing the compiler was that it would be too radical a change, and that really a linter should do this job.

The good news is that a new rule has recently been [merged into `tslint`'s codebase](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/1820) to provide warnings about this problem. As far as I can tell, though, the rule is not yet in a released version of `tslint`. Once it is released, if you set `strict-boolean-expressions` to `true` in your `tslint` rules, then `tslint` will warn you when you use a conditional with an expression that is not strictly boolean.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue and found the [`strict-boolean-expressions`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/) rule. Not the perfect answer for the example given by the OP, but might be helpful for others.

Activating this rule causes expressions like

```
if (nonBooleanCondition) {
```

to display the following warning:

> This type is not allowed in the 'if' condition because it is a [TYPE]. Only booleans are allowed.